# Playright ProtocolError: Browser closed when executing npx playwriht test --ui

Tags: browser, playwright

I installed the package for using playwright and configured it in order to be used locally after launching our server with `yarn run start`

There the file **playwright.config.ts**:

import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

```
/**
 * Read environment variables from file.
 * https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
 */
// require('dotenv').config();

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
export default defineConfig({
    testDir: './tests',
    /* Run tests in files in parallel */
    fullyParallel: true,
    /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
    //forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
    /* Retry on CI only */
    //retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
    /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
    //workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
    /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
    reporter: 'html',
    /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
    use: {
        /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
        // baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',

        /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
        trace: 'on-first-retry'
        /*launchOptions: {
            // Browser proxy option is required for Chromium on Windows.
            proxy: { server: 'per-context' }
        },*/
    },

    /* Configure projects for major browsers */
    projects: [
        /*{
            name: 'chromium',
            use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] }
        },

        {
            name: 'firefox',
            use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] }
        },

        {
            name: 'webkit',
            use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] }
        }*/

        /* Test against mobile viewports. */
        // {
        //   name: 'Mobile Chrome',
        //   use: { ...devices['Pixel 5'] },
        // },
        // {
        //   name: 'Mobile Safari',
        //   use: { ...devices['iPhone 12'] },
        // },

        /* Test against branded browsers. */
        {
            name: 'Microsoft Edge',
            use: { ...devices['Desktop Edge'], channel: 'msedge' }
        },
        {
            name: 'Google Chrome',
            use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'], channel: 'chrome' }
        }
    ]

    /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
    // webServer: {
    //   command: 'npm run start',
    //   url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    //   reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
    // },
});
```

I create one test in my file example.spec.ts

When I tried to execute the command to execute the test `npx playwriht test`, It's properly working:

But when I tried to execute the command to execute the test with the testing interface via the command `npx playwriht test --ui`, I received this error:

```
ProtocolError: Browser closed.
==================== Browser output: ====================
<launching> C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back
-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-component-update --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=Improved
CookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync,Translate --allow-pre-commit-input --disable
-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagg
ed-pdf --no-sandbox --app=data:text/html, --window-size=1280,800 --test-type= --user-data-dir=C:\Users\amadese\AppData\Local\Temp\playwright_chromiumdev_profile-tByI7k --remote-debugging-pipe about:blank
<launched> pid=25228
[pid=25228][out] Opening in existing browser session.
```

...

And the window of the testing interface is not properly loading:
[image]

I don't know how to solve that.
Could you please help me with that?